# Order list of movies and save sorting in cookies

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

[I did this project](https://github.com/saasbook/hw-rails-intro) and I'm going back over it and trying to optimize some stuff. This is the movies_controller.rb file, which is basically a table that I need to sort based on user parameters. What I really want to know here, is there a better way to save and assign the `@sort` and `@ratings_filter`? I just need to save them between sessions.

This is my first "revised" attempt:

```
def index
  @movies = Movie.all
  @all_ratings = Movie.all_ratings
  @ratings_filter = @all_ratings

  (params[:sort]) ? (@sort = params[:sort]) : (@sort = session[:sort])

  (params[:ratings] and params[:commit] == 'Refresh') ? 
  (@ratings_filter = params[:ratings].keys) : (@ratings_filter= session[:ratings] || @all_ratings)

  #save cookies
  if params[:sort] != session[:sort] or params[:ratings] != session[:ratings]
    session[:ratings] = @ratings_filter
    session[:sort] = @sort
    redirect_to movies_path :sort => @sort, :ratings => @ratings_filter# and return
  end

  @movies = Movie.sort_by_and_rating(@sort, @ratings_filter)

end
```

Here's the original for comparison:

```
    #params[:commit] has the value of the last button pressed
if (params[:ratings] and params[:commit] == 'Refresh')
    @ratings_filter = params[:ratings].keys
elsif params[:ratings]
    @ratings_filter = params[:ratings]
else
    @ratings_filter = session[:ratings] || @all_ratings
end

#@ratings_filter = params[:ratings].keys || session[:ratings] || @all_ratings

@sort = params[:sort] || session[:sort]

#save cookies
if params[:sort] != session[:sort] or params[:ratings] != session[:ratings]
    session[:ratings] = @ratings_filter
    session[:sort] = @sort
    redirect_to movies_path :sort => @sort, :ratings => @ratings_filter# and return
end

@movies = Movie.sort_by_and_rating(@sort, @ratings_filter)
```

[Here's my GitHub if you need other files for context](https://github.com/TommyK154/rottenpotatoes-rails-intro).

Answer (score 1):

You could improve your code by doing the following:

- Do not use `and`/`or` but `&&`/`||` since what you need here is boolean operators, not flow control operators. Take a look at [this](http://devblog.avdi.org/2014/08/26/how-to-use-rubys-english-andor-operators-without-going-nuts/) article for a great example on how and when to use each operator.
- You are constantly doing instance variable assignment at the one-liners conditionals which makes the code difficult to read (`conditional ? @i = x ? @i = y`). It's not wrong, but you could assign the result of the operation directly to the instance variable.
- You could extract some conditional checks to private methods to state in a more clear way what your code does.
- I'm not sure for this one, but I'll go for it. I think that you need the redirect when you set the `session`. You could just pass it to `Movie.sort_by_and_rating(...)`.

Here's a refactored version of your code:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
    @all_ratings = Movie.all_ratings    
    @sort = params[:sort] || session[:sort]
    @ratings_filter = params_rating? ? params[:ratings].keys : (session[:ratings] || @all_ratings)

    if set_cookies?
      session[:ratings] = @ratings_filter
      session[:sort] = @sort
    end

    @movies = Movie.sort_by_and_rating(@sort, @ratings_filter)
  end

  private

  def params_rating?
    params[:ratings] && params[:commit] == 'Refresh'
  end

  def set_cookies?
    params[:sort] != session[:sort] || params[:ratings] != session[:ratings]
  end
end
```